# Reduce number of white spaces

Tags: regex, notepad++, dreamweaver

I need to reduce number of white spaces in large number of files. For example:

```
tree house      big small like      go down up
         nice good  2323'0'-., 123       1234lk
```

I want it to be like this:

```
 tree house big small like go down up nice good  2323'0'-., 123 1234lk
```

It should go by logic somthing like this but I don't know how to do it:
one white space | one or more white spaces | any sign character not whitespace | one whitespace

in  Replace section it should be somthing like:
one whitespace | &1 | one whitespace

This is some logic but if I knew how to do it I would not ask questions.

Regards,
Nebojsa

Comment: Something like `\s+(\S+)\s+` -> `" \1 "`? Or `\s{2,}` -> `" "`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in notepad++

```
\s{2,}
```

change to simple space

Comment: This is solution. Simple and perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You need simple regex.

```
 regexp_replace(str,'\s+',' ','m');
```

'm' - modification for multiline